# Билеты на метро

Tags: python

Билет на одну поездку в метро стоит 15 рублей, билет на 10 поездок стоит 125 рублей, билет на 60 поездок стоит 440 рублей. Пассажир планирует совершить n поездок. Определите, сколько билетов каждого вида он должен приобрести, чтобы суммарное количество оплаченных поездок было не меньше n, а общая стоимость приобретенных билетов – минимальна.
Дано одно число n - количество поездок.
Выведите три целых числа, равные необходимому количеству билетов на 1, на 10, на 60 поездок.

Пишет неполное решение(92 из 100).

```
n = int(input())

a = n % 60

if a >= 40:
    t = n // 60 + 1
    n = 0
    m = 0
else:
    t = n // 60
    if (a % 10) >= 9:
        n = a // 10 + 1
        m = 0
    else:
        n = a // 10
        m = a % 10

print(m, n ,t)
```

Comment: а сколько денег вы потратите на 35 поездок?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло исправление первого условия на 35 вместо 40.

Comment: жестко прописанные условия  - это плохо. задача как раз на рекурсию - считаешь divmov и если вызов функции на остаток с более короткими билетами дороже - прибавляешь еще один билет этого уровня

Comment: Наверно вы правы, но тут сайт с задачами по конкретным темам и это как раз тема Условный Оператор, так что здесь и должны быть только условия.

Comment: Тут разбор этой задачи, правда на СИ++
https://youtu.be/IBABrQwJI6k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
a = n // 60
b = (n % 60) // 10
c = n % 10
if c * 15 > 125:
    c = 0
    b += 1
if c * 15 + b * 125 > 440:
    c = 0
    b = 0
    a += 1
print(c, b, a)
```

Comment: А тут точно ошибки нет?) a=n//60 может все же? Да и с странное

Comment: @pavel Да, перепутал операторы, пардон. Поправил.

Comment: Ваше решение вообще дает 0...

Comment: @Пельмень При каком введённом значении? ну и - не может оно дать ноль, ибо выводится ТРИ переменные.

Comment: Я имею ввиду в проверяющей системе за него дали 0 баллов из 100.

Comment: @Пельмень Ааа... ну на проверяющую системуу мне параллельно. Главное - программа даёт верные результаты.

Comment: Ну нет, проверяющая система как раз и проверяет только ответы...

Comment: Например 129. Ваш код выдает 9 1 2, хотя правильно 0 1 2.

Comment: @Пельмень Проверяющая система должна показывать, при каких исходных данных программа, по её мнению, даёт неверный результат. Или сообщать, что не выполнены какие-то иные требования. Вот и озвучьте. А догадываться, что там гремит в чёрном ящике - занятие неблагодарное.

Comment: И тут не могу с вами согласиться проверяющая система выдает только результат проверки, т.е. количество правильных ответов из общего количества набранных.

Comment: @Пельмень https://pyfiddle.io/ считает, что мой код при `n=129` выдаёт `(0, 1, 2)`. Вы нигде не ошиблись при наборе текста программы? на всякий случай - поменяйте имена переменных `a` и `c` на буквы, которые не спутать с кириллицей...

Comment: @Akina я бы только сделал `a, n = divmod(n, 60); b, c = divmod(n, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Более общий вариант решения(можно легко добавлять больше различных билетов):

```py
n = int(input())
prices = ((1, 15), (10, 125), (60, 440) ) # increasing order
tickets = []

for x in prices[::-1]:
    tickets.insert(0, n // x[0])
    n = n % x[0]

s = 0
lasti = 0
for i in range(1, len(tickets)):
    s += tickets[i-1] * prices[i-1][1]
    if s > prices[i][1]:
        for j in range(lasti, i):
            tickets[j] = 0
        tickets[i] += 1
        s = 0
        lasti = i

print(" ".join(map(str, tickets)))
#for x in tickets:
#   print(x, end=" ")
```