# Билеты на метро. Не понимаю логику

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Билет на одну поездку в метро стоит 15 рублей, билет на 10 поездок стоит 125 рублей, билет на 60 поездок стоит 440 рублей. Пассажир планирует совершить n поездок. Определите, сколько билетов каждого вида он должен приобрести, чтобы суммарное количество оплаченных поездок было не меньше n, а общая стоимость приобретенных билетов – минимальна.

**Входные данные**
Дано одно число n - количество поездок.

**Выходные данные**
Выведите три целых числа, равные необходимому количеству билетов на 1, на 10, на 60 поездок.

Comment: подумайте немного: есди покупать билеты на 10 поездок, то 20 поездок - 250 рублей , 40 - 500, значит на 40 поездок выгодней взять один билет на 60

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Билеты на метро](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041023/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно, Ватсон! :)

Берем простое жадное решение, а затем проверяем, нельзя ли заменить одинарные билеты одним на 10, потом - билеты на 10 одним на 60. Если первое условие отрицательно - проверяем, нельзя ли заменить одинарные билеты и все по 10 - на один на 60 поездок.

```
int main()
{
    int n, m60 = 0, m10 = 0, m1 = 0;
    cin >> n;
    m60 = n/60;    // Минимальное число на 60 поездок
    n = n % 60;    // остаток
    if (n)
    {
        m10 = n/10;   // Остаток - на 10 поездок
        m1  = n%10;   // Остаток для одинарных
    }
    if (m1*15 > 125)  // Проверяем, не имеет ли смысла заменить одинарные одним на 10
    {
        m1 = 0;
        m10++;
    }
    if (m1*15 + m10*125 > 440) // или все на 1 и 10 - одним билетом на 60
    {
        m1 = m10 = 0;
        m60++;
    }

    cout << m1 << " " << m10 << " " << m60 << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Допустим n = 12 
Это 10 + 2
1-ое основание 10 (125р цена билетов)
2-ое 2 (2 * 15 = 30)
125 + 30 = оптимальная цена 

Или

Допустим n = 256 (кол-во поездок)

Делим наше n на каждый из трёх видов билетов:
Вид_1: 1 поездка = 15
Вид_2: 10 поездок = 125
Вид_3: 60 поездок = 440

И далее проверками if проверяем на целое.
1 шаг.
Если (n / Вид_3 != 0) то берём целое от деления и умножаем на 440 и получаем сумму_1
n - (Вид_3 * целое_от_деления) = получаем остаток поездок
шаг 2.
Если (n / Вид_2 != 0) то берём целое от деления и умножаем на 125 и получаем сумму_2
n - (Вид_2 * целое_от_деления) = получаем остаток поездок
шаг 3.
Если (n / Вид_3 != 0) то берём целое от деления и умножаем на 10 и получаем сумму_1
n - (Вид_1 * целое_от_деления) = получаем остаток поездок

оптимальная_цена_за_n_поездок = сумма_1 + сумма_2 + сумма_3

Для n поездок, необходимо купить билетов вида:
Вид_1 = целое от деления
Вид_2 = целое от деления
Вид_3 = целое от деления


PS Думаю этот псевдокод будет понятен :)
```

Comment: Следует ли понимать так, что для 19 поездок решением является 1 билет на 10 поездок и 9 билетов по одной поездке?...

Comment: да, всё верно;
и помните о типах, их 3 в условии;
если n = 19, то;
1 тип билетов (x125);
9 тип билетов (х15);
1 * 125 + 9 * 15 = оптимальная_цена;

Comment: Т.е. оптимальная цена для 19 поездок, по-вашему, 260. А мне кажется, что 2 билета по 10 поездок обеспечат те же самые поездки, но за 125*2 = 250, и что 250 все же меньше 260. Если бы разговор шел об общем количестве билетов, или билетов должно было быть ровно на количество поездок - я бы с вами согласился, но для данной задачи жадный алгоритм не проходит.

Comment: Согласен полностью, Harry.
Не вник до конца в задачу, продолжим думать :) Спасибо за указание моей ошибки